# A recurrence relation for $\zeta(2n)$ - reference request

Tags: reference-request, riemann-zeta-function

In the textbook https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783034851688 (Klassische elementare Analysis, by M. Koecher) the following elegant recurrence relation is proved for $\zeta(2n)$ (on p. 157):
$$\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\zeta(2n)=\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n-1}\zeta(2m)\,\zeta(2n-2m). \tag{1}$$
In fact (1) is equivalent to Euler's recurrence relation for Bernoulli numbers (independently found by Ramanujan)
$$(2n+1)B_{2n}=-\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2m}B_{2m}\,B_{2n-2m}. \tag{2}$$ 
Why, In contrast to (2), (1) can seldom be found in the literature (I was able to find only https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00591-007-0022-2 that mentions (1))? Are there any other references that discuss (1)?

**P.S. In addition to juan's answer.**
G.T. Williams was not the first to state the result in this form. It can be found at least in N. Nielsen, Handbuch der theorie der gammafunktion, Leipzig:
Druck und Verlag von B.G. Teubner, 1906, p. 49. I found this reference thanks to the paper "Some identities involving the Riemann zeta function. II." by   R. Sitaramachandrarao and B. Davis, Indian J. Pure Appl. Math. 17(10):1175–1186, 1986. https://www.insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJPAM/20005a50_1175.pdf This reference also has (1) and  proves (among others) an interesting generalization of (1):
$$4\sum\limits_{i+j+k=n}\zeta(2i)\zeta(2j)\zeta(2k)=(n+1)(2n+1)\zeta(2n)-6\zeta(2)\zeta(2n-2),$$ where $n\ge 3$ and the sum extends over all ordered triples $(i,j,k)$ of positive integers satisfying $i+j+k=n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have this recurrence in my collection of problems for my lessons in Analytic Number Theory. I have there  the reference:

P. Ribenboim, Classical Theory of Algebraic Numbers, Springer, New York, 2001, p. 503.

I add a note that related formulas can be found in

S. Sekatskii, Novel integral representations of the Riemann zeta-function and Dirichlet eta-function, close expressions.... https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.02150 
(I have not checked this paper, but contains some interesting similar relations).

After several hours I find the formula in Theorem 1 of

G. T. Williams, "A new method of evaluating $\zeta(2n)$", Amer. Math. Soc, 60, (1953) 19--25.

The author of this paper think he is the first to state the result in this form.

Comment: it's eq. 27 of Sekatskii

Answer (score 7):

For a variation on the *bilinear* recursion relation in the OP that involves only sums up to $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, rather than up to $n-1$, see [1,2].

Expanding the question to interesting and little known recursion relations for the zeta function I could mention this *linear* relation [3,4]:

$$(-1)^n\frac{\pi^{2n}n}{(2n+1)!}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\frac{\pi^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}\zeta(2n-2k)=0.$$

[1] H.-T. Kuo, [A recurrence formula for $\zeta(2n)$](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183513890) (1949).
[2] L. Carlitz, [A recurrence formula for $\zeta(2n)$](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0133306-X/S0002-9939-1961-0133306-X.pdf) (1961).
[3] I. Song, [A recursive formula for even order harmonic series](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0377042788902749?via%3Dihub) (1987).
[4] M. Merca, [On the Song recurrence relation for the Riemann zeta function](http://real.mtak.hu/71510/) (2016).